# Is there and equivalent of WebGL but using DirectX?

Tags: directx, webgl

Can anyone tell me if there is an equivalent of WebGL but using DirectX API?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WebGL is using DirectX](https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) on windows, otherwise no because WebGL as a web technology is about platform independence, which DirectX(or better Direct3D) due to its proprietary nature doesn't offer.